# Как разбить текстовый столбец на список слов по разделителю?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется датасет, в котором одна колонка с набором данных типа `object` (кондитерка). Например:

- 1 объект "шоколад, пряники, конфеты, зефир";
- n-ый объект "шоколад, пряники, конфеты, печенье, вафли"

То есть объекты имеют разную длину, но каждое слово отделяется от предыдущего запятой.

Хочется разделить каждый объект на части и сделать кодирование *One Hot*. Если со вторым мне более менее ясно, то вот как разделить строку на несколько объектов? Тут - творческий ступор...

Comment: Объекты нужны какого-то определённого типа или список строк подойдёт? И вообще, что подразумевается под словом "объект"? У вас же просто строки.

Comment: [str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) же: data_string.split(',')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [452]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

In [453]: df = pd.DataFrame({"items": ["шоколад, пряники, конфеты, зефир", "шоколад, пряники, конфеты, печенье, вафли"]})

In [454]: df
Out[454]: 
                                       items
0           шоколад, пряники, конфеты, зефир
1  шоколад, пряники, конфеты, печенье, вафли

In [455]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=False)

In [456]: X = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df["items"].str.split(",\s*")),
                           columns=mlb.classes_,
                           index=df.index)

In [457]: X
Out[457]: 
   вафли  зефир  конфеты  печенье  пряники  шоколад
0      0      1        1        0        1        1
1      1      0        1        1        1        1
```

---

На будущее: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

---

**UPD:** используем данные из Excel файла:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Food.xlsx", sheet_name="2020")

t = df["Кондитерка, выпечка, сухофрукты"].str.lower().fillna(",").str.split(",\s*")

X = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(t), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index).drop(columns="")
```

результат:

```
In [35]: X
Out[35]: 
     арбуз  батончики  безе  блин  блины  будочки  булочки  бургеры  варенье  вафли  газировка  зебра  ...  торт  тортик  тортики  трафлы  финик  финики  фрукты  халва  чернослив  чизкейк  чокопай  шоколад
0        0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
1        0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
2        0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
3        0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
4        0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
..     ...        ...   ...   ...    ...      ...      ...      ...      ...    ...        ...    ...  ...   ...     ...      ...     ...    ...     ...     ...    ...        ...      ...      ...      ...
361      0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      1          0        0        0        1
362      0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
363      0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
364      0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0
365      0          0     0     0      0        0        0        0        0      0          0      0  ...     0       0        0       0      0       0       0      0          0        0        0        0

[366 rows x 63 columns]
```

Comment: спасибо! Попробовал применить ко всему фичу - получил ошибку TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @Pascal16, приведите в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных, который позволит воспроизвести ошибку...

Comment: @Pascal16, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: df = df = pd.read_excel('Food.xlsx', sheet_name='2020')
X = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df["Кондитерка, выпечка, сухофрукты"].str.split(",\s*")), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

Последняя строчка не запускается. ОшибкаTypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Можете выложить ваш Excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник ?

Comment: Я бы скрин прислал, но не знаю как.

Comment: Я точно не буду вбивать данные с картинки только для того, чтобы помочь вам ;) [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/dvnwuple#

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117807/discussion-between-pascal16-and-maxu).

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, обычный `CountVectorizer`, который часто используют для текстов, тут тоже подойдёт. Но надо помнить, что у него по умолчанию есть некоторые параметры, которые, например, отбросят слова длиной меньше 2-х символов. Часть кода я покрал у MaxU уважаемого, раз уж есть готовая заготовка:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"items": ["шоколад, пряники, конфеты, зефир", "шоколад, пряники, конфеты, печенье, вафли"]})
cvec = CountVectorizer()
X = cvec.fit_transform(df['items'])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(X.todense(), columns=cvec.get_feature_names())
```

Comment: да, CountVectorizer здесь более уместен ;)